# What gets assigned to a variable if we try to assign a comment to it?

Tags: php

What value does the $xyz get assigned? Does it get a null value or is there any error? There is also an error_reporting(0) function.

```
error_reporting(0); 
$xyz =// removed;
```

Comment: It should throw a fatal error

Comment: As it is, it's a syntax error.

Comment: There no rocket science in this you can easily try and check yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd get a syntax error, like so:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

So, `$xyz` wouldn't have a value, PHP would just exit because of the syntax error, and you'd never even get to see what the value was.

([See for yourself](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4Artagovyi@KLUgv6gkMy9dw0DTWoFLpaKySsFWX1@hKDU3vyw1xfr/fwA))

---

<s>Since you've set `error_reporting(0)` you won't get any errors, so `$xyz` has a value of `NULL`.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4Artagovyi@KLUgv6gkMy9dw0DTWoFLpaKySsFWX1@hKDU3vyw1xZqrLLEoPqU0t0ADJKVp/f8/AA)
If you don't even set the `$xyz`, it's still `NULL`:
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4Artagovyi@KLUgv6gkMy9dw0DTmqsssSg@pTS3QEOlorJK0/r/fwA)
Effectively, PHP just ignores that line, it's like `$xyz` was never set, so `var_dump`ing it returns `NULL`.</s>

(Turns out that `$xyz` was being set to the output of `var_dump`, so there was no syntax error. Thanks to [@Bytewave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3397227/bytewave) for figuring that out)

Comment: If you look at the example provided, it would be a syntax error, showing a blank white as the engine cannot carry on processing. The closing syntax for the variable `;`  would be commented out, so it would not be picked up

Comment: @DarylGill, since there's an `error_reporting(0);`, it completely ignores the syntax error, and just continues as if there's no declaration. Without the `error_reporting(0);`, there _would_ be a syntax error, and the whole program would stop, I agree.

Comment: There is no error reported, but there is still an error. Nothing will display, it wont be ignored.. Just wont display the actual message

Comment: @David That isn't how syntax errors work. Just because you have reporting turned off doesn't mean the parser changes its behavior. If the code can't parse, it won't run, plain and simple.

Comment: @Bytewave It works for me, both locally in the cli and browser, and in tio.run and [eval.in](https://eval.in/973699). What version of PHP does if fail for you on?

Comment: Wait... oh, duh. It works because you're assigning the return value of `var_dump` to `$xyz`. The comment removes the semicolon so the assignment carries over to the next line. This is independent of any `error_reporting` setting, though. Whoops!

Comment: @Bytewave Ohhh!! I totally didn't think of that. _\*facepalm\*_ Thanks for working that out :) Right, without the `var_dump` it throws a syntax error now.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a comment to a variable because when the script is executed, all comments are ignored so you'll end up with a syntax error. As you can see in the syntax highlighting in your question, the semicolon at the end is greyed out because everything after the `//` is ignored.